# I am having trouble designing a REST api call using requests to hit a Kinetica DB instance to confirm it is working

Tags: python, api, rest, kinetica

Here is the code I tried:

```py
import requests
test = requests.request("GET",'https://mycoolurl.host/admin/verifydb')
print(test.json())
```

It results in a `400` error.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that, according to [Kinetica's documentation](https://www.kinetica.com/docs/api/rest/index.html), every call is a POST call even if you are not sending data into the system and only expecting data coming back. Thus, this version modified to a POST, from above works, and results in a `200` and json data back from the server:

```py
test = requests.request("POST",'https://mycoolurl.host/admin/verifydb', json={'options': {}})
print(test.json())
```

Comment: Note this is correct for Kinetica Version 7.0x, future versions are not guaruanteed to work the same.